# Папку vendor (composer) надо добавлять в gitignore?

Tags: php, composer

Собственно сам вопрос в теме. Допустим я делаю `composer update packet` - пакет обновляется, обновляются файлы в папке vendor. Git конечно заметит эти изменения.

Но если я его исключу, тогда на dev-машине у меня может быть изменённая версия пакетов, а на prod-машине старая, ну либо вручную мне нужно будет тоже на prod-сервере сделать такую же команду `composer update packet`

Answer (score 3):

Директория, в которую вы ставите пакеты конечно должна быть исключена из контроля версия. Для того, что бы версии пакетов совпадали в точности, у композера есть специальный файл `composer.lock`, в который он пишет информацию об установлены пакетах и хеши коммитов, что бы в точности такие же версии поставить в другом месте.

При разворачивании проекта, в связи с вышесказанным, нужно использовать только команду

```
composer install
```

иначе можете получить разные версии установленных пакетов. А когда нужно обновить сами библиотеки, то уже используем команду `composer update`, и потом фиксируем изменения в файле `composer.lock` и коммитим.

В самом простом виде процесс обновления может выглядеть так:

```
composer update
git add composer.lock
git commit -m "Update some libs"
git push
```

На другой машине

```
git pull
composer install
```

Answer (score 2):

Ту проблему о которой вы говорите решает `composer.lock`
Предназначение `.lock` файла - записать в него непосредственно те версии, которые были установлены и под которые велась разработка и тестирование, чтобы в дальнейшем можно было их переустановить.
Это означает, что если у вас в `composer.json` указана версия `1.*`, а ваш коллега запустил `composer update`, которая установила 1.2.4 и закоммитил файл `composer.lock`, то вы, запустив `composer install`, получите ту же `1.2.4`, даже если `1.3.0` уже вышла.
Это позволяет быть уверенным, что каждый, кто работает над вашим проектом будет иметь абсолютно одинаковые версии пакетов.

Answer (score 0):

Она по идее по умолчанию в игноре должна лежать. Иначе какой тогда смысл composer.json'а